# Check if a threadpool have tasks that are waiting for execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

So this is the scenario I am trying to come up with a solution for:

> You got a parking house with 2000 free slots. It has 4 entrances. When the parking house is full, there is only allowed 50 cars to wait in each entrance.

What I ended up doing was creating a thread pool with 2000 threads, and then 4 threads representing the entrances. At random intervals, they create car `Tasks`(they basically just call `Thread.sleep()`) and submits them to the thread pool.

The problem arises when the thread pool is busy executing 2000 tasks, and newly submitted tasks gets put in a queue to await execution. How do I deal with waiting in the entrances instead? I can't seem to find a way to check if the thread pool is "full" or anything like that. Or maybe my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: Do you have to use threading for this scenario? If not take a look at Queues. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: Yes, both threads and threadpool are required. As I see it, even if I used queues in the entrances, they would still just submit to the executor and build a another queue.

Comment: There is a ThreadPoolExecutor constructor that accepts a BlockingQueue together with a  RejectedExecutionHandler. This looks promising to me to solve this nice challenge. I think you have to do some additional coding to represent the 4 entrances. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory,%20java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler)

Comment: I'l sure to check that out! But I seem to have solved it using semaphores and callbacks. Each entrance thread has a semaphore with 50 keys. When it has made a cartask, it takes a key. The cartask then has a callback which is called after it has slept. The callback just returns one key to the semaphore. This seems to work fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now how do I deal with waiting in the entrances instead? I can't seem to find a way to check if the threadpool is "full" or anything like that.

Hrm.  There are many ways to do this using the Java concurrent classes.  One way would be to have a `BlockingQueue` with a limited size of 2000 that would represent parking lot slots.  Then have 4 single-threaded executor-service thread-pools each with a queue of 50 representing the 4 entrances.  Once the 51st car attempts to get queued at an entrance, the `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown.

Something like:

```
final int NUM_SPACES_IN_LOT = 2000;
final int ENTRANCE_QUEUE_SIZE = 50;
final BlockingQueue<Car> parkingLot = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(NUM_SPACES_IN_LOT);
...
ExecutorService entrance1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(ENTRANCE_QUEUE_SIZE));
ExecutorService entrance1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(ENTRANCE_QUEUE_SIZE));
ExecutorService entrance1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(ENTRANCE_QUEUE_SIZE));
ExecutorService entrance1 = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(ENTRANCE_QUEUE_SIZE));
...
private class ParkCar implements Runnable {
    private final Car car;
    public ParkCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
    public run() {
        parkingLot.put(car);
    }
}
...
Car car = new Car();
try {
   entrance1.submit(new ParkCar(car));
} catch (RejectedExecutionException jee) {
   // entrance is full
}
...
// remove a car from the lot, warning this is O(N)
parkingLot.remove(car);
```

You need a per entrance queue and per entrance threads to do the concurrent parking.  You could call `entranceX.setRejectedExecutionHandler(...)` to set a handler if an entrance was full if you didn't want it to throw an exception.

The thing I don't like about this implementation is that the `parkingLot.remove(...)` is `O(N)` but there isn't a blocking set without writing it yourself.